# Compilation problem with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

The following code does not produce the figure expected.

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
    \definecolor{prune}{rgb}{0.6,0.00,0.48}
    \definecolor{bleu}{rgb}{0.1,0.05,0.5}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      [restrict x to domain=-4:8, xmax=8, xmin=-4,
      restrict y to domain=-5:6, ymax=6, ymin=-5,
      x=0.5cm,
      y=0.5cm,
      axis x line=middle,
      axis y line=middle, 
      line width = 0.4mm,
      xtick=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,
      samples=1000,
      >=stealth,
      compat=1.8,
       ]
     \addplot[line width=1,smooth,domain=-4:8,bleu] {-.25*x^2+x+3} ;
     \draw[dashed,thin,prune] (2,-5)--(2,6) ;
     \draw[dashed,thin,prune] (0,4) --(2,4) ; 
     \node[below left] (O) at (0,0) {O} ; 
     \node[above right,prune] (S) at (2,4) {S}; 
     \node[left,prune] (text1) at (0,4) {$f\left(-\dfrac{b}{2a}\right)$} ;
     \node[below right,prune] (text2) at (2,0) {$-\dfrac{b}{2a}$} ;    
     \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{document}
```

Here is the figure I want :

[image]

Comment: Edit the image in code ...

Comment: @ juanuni What do you mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `axis cs:` (axis coordinates) before each coordinate like `(axis cs:0,0)`, because the axis coordinates are different from the actual ones.

I changed your code slightly, and enlarged the maximum axis coordinates because your plot gets cut otherwise. Also, there's no need to specify the compatibility in two places. The first one was the right one.

I also switched to the `arrows.meta` library (`arrows` seems to be deprecated), while `bending` is for properly placing the arrow tip on the curve.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}

\definecolor{prune}{rgb}{0.6,0.00,0.48}
\definecolor{bleu}{rgb}{0.1,0.05,0.5}

\tikzset{
    mye/.style={dashed, thin, prune}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth}]
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-4, xmax=10,
    ymin=-6, ymax=6, 
    enlarge x limits=1,
    enlarge y limits=0.2,
    x=0.5cm,
    y=0.5cm,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle, 
    line width = 0.4mm,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    samples=1000
]

\addplot[line width=1,smooth,domain=-4:8,bleu,-{<[flex=0.5]}] {-.25*x^2+x+3};
\draw[mye] (axis cs:2,-5) -- (axis cs:2,6);
\draw[mye] (axis cs:0,4) -- (axis cs:2,4); 
\node[anchor=north east] (O) at (axis cs:0,0) {O}; 
\node[above right,prune] (S) at (axis cs:2,4) {S}; 
\node[left,prune] (text1) at (axis cs:0,4) {$f\left(-\dfrac{b}{2a}\right)$};
\node[below right,prune] (text2) at (axis cs:2,0) {$-\dfrac{b}{2a}$};   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Alenanno Sorry for the late response! Thank you very much, I have now to place the basis vectors and labels x and y.

Answer (score 1):

In online compiler appears error with `compat=1.8`. In your code `compat=1.8` appears in `\pgfplotsset` and like option in `axis` environment. I delete that and produce this

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\definecolor{prune}{rgb}{0.6,0.00,0.48}
\definecolor{bleu}{rgb}{0.1,0.05,0.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  [restrict x to domain=-4:8, xmax=8, xmin=-4,
  restrict y to domain=-5:6, ymax=6, ymin=-5,
  x=0.5cm,
  y=0.5cm,
  axis x line=middle,
  axis y line=middle, 
  line width = 0.4mm,
  xtick=\empty,
  ytick=\empty,
  samples=1000,
  >=stealth
   ]
 \addplot[line width=1,smooth,domain=-4:8,blue] {-.25*x^2+x+3} ;
 \draw[dashed,thin,prune] (2,-5)--(2,6) ;
 \draw[dashed,thin,prune] (0,4) --(2,4) ; 
 \node[below left] (O) at (0,0) {O} ; 
 \node[above right,prune] (S) at (2,4) {S}; 
 \node[left,prune] (text1) at (0,4) {$f\left(-\dfrac{b}{2a}\right)$} ;
 \node[below right,prune] (text2) at (2,0) {$-\dfrac{b}{2a}$} ;    
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

What is bad? The letter S? ... in your code appears like `node`.

Comment: @ juanuni I added the expected figure (made with PSTricks). How to add a larger image on the forum ?

Comment: @Fabrice try with `\addplot` instead `\draw`

Comment: @ juanuni This does not work, but thank you for the attention paid to the question.

Comment: Oh, is not for your last picture in your question. Alenano did you a response before ...